# Reverse url not working for ReadOnlyModelViewSet - Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am getting a rather pesky error - reverse for 'myad-list' not found. 'myad-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name. The similar code is working when I used ModelViewSet

My view set class:-

```
class GetMyAdsViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
"""Get my ads"""
serializer_class = serializers.BookSerializer
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
queryset = Book.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self):
    """
        Filtering according to query params
    """
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    queryset = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
    return queryset
```

My url file:-

```
router.register('myads', views.GetMyAdsViewSet)
```

My code in test file:-

```
MY_ADS_URL = reverse("book:myads-list")
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [the DRF docs of routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage), if you don't provide the third optional argument for basename during `router.register()`, the basename will be generated from the queryset name, and may not be what you want.

To be sure about your basename you can register it like this:

```py
router.register('myads', views.GetMyAdsViewSet, 'myads')
```